# Read the last console line in Swift xCode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

I want to be able to read the LAST console line and store that as a variable.

I want to do this because I've got a table view that has items in my array and I want to make my app so that when you press one of the cells, it changes the label text on the next screen to the text of cell selected.
Thus far, I have only got to being able to println the cell text but I don't know how to transfer it.
I think by being able to store the println as a variable and sending it over using the `prepareForSegue` may work.

e.g:

```
import UIKit

var storedString = String()

println("hello")
```

[What is here..???]

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    var nextViewController: SecondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as SecondViewController

    nextViewController.recievedString = storedString

}
```

Comment: DON'T TRY TO TRANSFER DATA THOUGH THE COMMAND LINE! That's like the worst thing to do, pass it in your program! Much easier and safer and not troublesome and robust and etc.

Comment: Um, sorry, how do I do that? I'm still very new to programing @Kametrixom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try storing the text in the cell rather than printing it, like where you're printing it, instead set storedString equal to it, kinda like

```
    //You were doing something like this
    println(cellText)

    //instead do something like this
    self.storedString = cellText
```

then, since your prepareForSegue method looks like it should pass storedString in as recievedString correctly, in the viewDidLoad method of SecondViewController add

```
    self.labelName.text = self.recievedString
```

Hopefully that should work!